# IIS High CPU Load: GetMetaDataInternalInterfaceFromPublic+0x935c

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, iis-7, cpu-usage

Currently our staging IIS puts 100% load on the CPU.

(I wasn't allowed to post with an image so I'll link it: http://i40.tinypic.com/1444qww.png)

I currently have been unable to find the cause of this behavior since the stack of the thread that causes the high load does not contain any application specific references. If anyone sees more in this screenshot then I or had a similar experience I'm glad to hear it.

Info:
Windows Server 2k8R2

If any more information is required I shall try to provide.

Thanks.

Comment: Impossible to say why, as you do not say what you are doing. A guess, dependency injection...

Comment: No we don't use dependency injection yet, that's one of the next steps we'll be trying to incorporate (it's legacy code we're slowly upgrading to a decent architecture) What we added in this release is mainly some caching. Since we didn't change anything clear that'd cause this kind of spikes in CPU load it's quiet the mystery to me why this is happening. Hence I hoped that someone here would've seen the same behavior on this specific method from mscorwks and point out some places where I might go looking for the cause of this.

Comment: Does IIS hang, or is it just slow? Is the stack trace always the same when the CPU is maxed-out? You might try enabling IIS tracing, to see if anything stands out.

Comment: It is just slow, after about 1 minute the requested page comes through. The stacktrace appears to be the same all the time, I've not caught any other stacktraces. I will try IIS tracing today.

Comment: The result of the trace was the following: http://i39.tinypic.com/r7rns5.png As you can see I have about 20s pageload (for a partial view) and I have all 0ms and 15ms results in timing on the IIS trace. I believe this points out to the fact that I should really be searching inside of our application. I identified a group of pages which exhibits this behavior and a group that doesn't, right now I'm trying to figure out the difference between them.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm seeing this on a database/NHibernate  heavy process. Are you by any chance doing something database-heavy? Or using NHibernate?

Comment: @MauricioScheffer: Yes we found that one of the business layer classes was loading a 50k+ table into a dictionary in memory in its initialization. This caused the long wait as well as the high load. Changing this swiftly fixed our problem.

Comment: @IvanL Could you please add your last comment as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We found that one of the business layer classes was loading a 50k+ table into a dictionary in memory in its initialization. This caused the long wait as well as the high load. Changing this swiftly fixed our problem.